# Android: Date Dialog get on onDateChange

Tags: java, android

I've got my date dialog working fine, however I can't seem to get the onDateChange to let me use the dialog.getMonth, getDate etc to add to my onclick event to save the date.

Here is my code;

```
 public void addInstallDate(View view){
        Log.e("Showing Dialog", "Dialog Date");

                DatePickerDialog dateDlg = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                        {
                           Time chosenDate = new Time();
                           chosenDate.set(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);
                           long dtDob = chosenDate.toMillis(true);
                           CharSequence strDate = DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy", dtDob);

                        }

                        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        }


                }, 2011,0, 1);


                        dateDlg.setButton("OK", new 
                                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                                    }
                                });

                         dateDlg.setMessage("Install Date?");
                         dateDlg.show();
        }
```

Inside (below function) i've tried to use dateDlg.getMonth() etc but they are not available to me

```
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "they are not available to me" ?

Comment: Hey - Thanks for replying, http://www.screenup.info/uploads/5034759.jpeg <- like that

Answer (score 3):

The getMonth() method is defined on DatePicker, not DatePickerDialog:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html

However, as you've shown, the DatePickerDialog#onDateChanged method actually provides the month that was *selected* as one of its parameters, which is probably what you are looking for:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html

If you need to, you can access the month set in the DatePicker instance by calling

```
view.getMonth()
```

in the onDateChanged callback.

Comment: Does that mean I can't get access to them from a datepickerdialog? I can't do DatePicker.getMonth();

Comment: getMonth() is an instance method - I'll add that to my answer

Comment: Thankyou for your update.  However i'm getting the following error: The method onDateChanged(DatePicker, int, int, int) from the type new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){} is never used locally - so when I try and log monthofYear it never hits/ updates

Comment: @TomBeech I suspect that you have accidentally moved the definition of onDateChanged inside the OnDateSetListener implementation, whereas it should be defined inside the DatePickerDialog implementation. Check your braces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience ireddick - As far as I can tell, the braces are in the right place (as eclipse shows here: http://www.screenup.info/uploads/3525927.jpeg)

Comment: @TomBeech You need to insert another closing brace after the closing brace of onDateSet to end the class definition. If you fix the indentation of onDateSet then you should see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the **OnDateSetListener** callback, it won't work. That listener is for **onDateSet** only, not **onDateChanged**.

To use the **onDateChanged** callback, you must implement the **DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener** interface.

And then you have to call getDatePicker on your dialog. then you call **init(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener onDateChangedListener)**

If you must support lower than API level 11, you can't use this solution. You would have to extend DatePickerDialog class to be able to set a callback onDateChanged.

Something like this:

```
public class Pre11DatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {

    DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener    dateChangedCallback;

    public Pre11DatePickerDialog( Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth ) {
        super( context, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth );
    }

    public void setOnDateChangedListener( DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener dateChangedCallback ) {
        this.dateChangedCallback = dateChangedCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged( DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day ) {
        super.onDateChanged( view, year, month, day );
        if ( dateChangedCallback != null ) {
            this.dateChangedCallback.onDateChanged( view, year, month, day );
        }
    }
}
```

And then when you create your dialog you will have to set the listener like this:

```
Pre11DatePickerDialog dialog = new Pre11DatePickerDialog( getActivity(), this, year, month, day );

dialog.setOnDateChangedListener( this );
```

And now you can implement **onDateChanged()**:

```
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged( DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth ) {
        //Do your thing here
    }
```

Hope this helps, Cheers